# What will be Procfile for node+Angular 2 application?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, heroku

I have an Angular 2 application. I want to deploy it to the Heroku. So it requires a Procfile. For my Node.js application, into Procfile I used

```
node serverName.js
```

But in the Angular 2 application I can not figure out what I should put down in Procfile to deploy this application to Heroku.
Here's my application [Weather Application](https://github.com/bmshamsnahid/Weather-Application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular is a front-end framework, so it would have no use for a Procfile. What is the back0enbd for your Angular App?

Also, the Procfile should specify the type of dyno, so:
`web: node serverName.js`